# How to read the value of the ui:inputText in the client side controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a `<ui:inputText>` in my component. when I try to access the value of the textbox in the client side controller, I get undefined. Should the textbox be within a form?

Component:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="comments">{!$Label.c.Comments}</label>
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<ui:inputtextarea aura:id="comments"  class="slds-input" rows="3" value="{!v.comments}" updateOn="keyup"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.buttonClicked}">Save</button>
```

Controller:

```
buttonClicked:function(component, event, helper) {


    var commentsControl = component.find("comments");
    console.log(component.find("comments"));
    console.log("event:"+commentsControl.get("v.value")) ;


}
```

Comment: can you please post the complete error message?

Comment: there is no error. I get the value as undefined or I get the default value that is set. Unable to read the data that is entered in the textbox.

Comment: I have this sort of markup working fine without a form.

Comment: The keyup Event for the textbox was not getting fired because of the Renderer.js file

Answer (score 2):

Since you bound the value to "comments":

```
value="{!v.comments}"
```

You should have an attribute by the same name:

```
<aura:attribute name="comments" type="String" />
```

And in your controller, you can access it directly:

```
var comments = component.get("v.comments");
console.log("comments: " + comments);
```

Comment: Have an attribute and tried this too. No luck

Comment: I recently stumbled upon the same problem. To actually get the value you have to "submit". In my case I'm using a `keyup` event and it forces me to press Enter to get the value

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the attribute named `comments` of type String:

**Component:**

```
<aura:attribute name="comments" type="String" default="" />

<div class="slds-form-element">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="comments">{!$Label.c.Comments}</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <ui:inputtextarea aura:id="comments"  class="slds-input" rows="3" value="{!v.comments}" updateOn="keyup"/>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.buttonClicked}">Save</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
buttonClicked:function(component, event, helper) {              
    var commentsControl = component.find("comments");
    console.log(component.find("comments"));
    console.log("event:"+commentsControl.get("v.value")) ;          
}
```